# Building GUI for social networking app

Tags: java, user-interface, social-networking

I am building a social networking app with java(using swing) . Which container Can I use for posts section to have post itself a place for comments and a like button .I also want to merge it with a scroll bar so the post will be displayed upon each other.

Comment: Offtopic, but I would recommend to use HTML5/JS/CSS to build a frontend rather than Java Swing. This library is a bit obsolete. Unless you are doing a homework of course.

Comment: I know but it's our final project for AP

Answer (score 0):

For posts section you could use a `JLabel` a `JTextField` or a `JEditorPane` or a `JTextArea`. All of there should work and when you add a `JTextField` a `JEditorPane` or a `JTextArea` to a `JScrollpane` you can have scrollbar. For button you could just use a `JButton` with an `ImageIcon` with a like picture or you can just use a `JButton` with the tekst like: `new JButton("Like");` and as the main container you should use a `JPanel` and the frame is obviously a `JFrame`.

I hope this helps and good luck.
P.S. If you have any more questions feel free to ask them.

Comment: the problem I have is that I don't how to combine a JTextArea, a JTextField, and a JButton to appear on all posts like facebook!

Comment: You add them to a JPanel and use a LayoutManager to organize them.

Comment: and will it be scrollable ?

Comment: You can add any component to a JScrollPane to make it scrollable

Comment: As the last question suppose that I have jpanel with those elements. Is this correct to make an instance for every post from mentioned jpanel and the add it to an other scrollable jpanel?

Comment: Yeah I guess so altleast that's what I would do after all Java is an object orientated programming language.